# Read files from client folder and upload to server - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, upload, client

What is the best way to get files from client folder (a folder that the client will choose the path) and upload to server?

Thanks.

Comment: detail: Must be a web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

For privacy reasons, code from web sites running in a browser context is not allowed to enumerate files or directories on the client machine and send that information to a server.  Imagine what would happen if it could!

You could possibly get around this limitation with some more complicated solution that includes a client side install (e.g. an ActiveX control) but this is simply not possible with ASP.NET alone.

Comment: Thanks John.. I would like to have this solution, if the client allow the permission to read the directory. Maybe with java applet. There is another solution in another tecnology? Because the first solution the i thougt was do a desktop application.

Comment: You'll need either a standard WIndows desktop application, or if you really want it to be browser based you can write an [ActiveX control](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2011/12/05/how-to-develop-and-deploy-activex-control-in-c/) and embed it on a page.  The user will need to accept the installation of the ActiveX control; after that, it can access the local filesystem without issue.

Comment: It was better you said 'I want my website access the client files and folders'